# Visual Studio Installer Sub-directory

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation

I am building an install msi using the Visual Studio 2010 installer.

I need to add files to a subdirectory of my installation. I know about the Add Files function but that will add them to the main directory.  I don’t see how to add them automatically to a subdirectory. In my case it is the /Report subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click your Installer project, go to View->File System.

Now right-click on the 'Application Folder' and select Add->Folder (see screenshot below). Name your folder 'Reports' or whatever you need. 
Done.

Now you can place your files under [Application Folder\Reports] on the target machine.

[image]